# serialization and desrializing the Objects in xml

Tags: c#

I have Class Add,Class Subtract,Class Multiplication.And every class has the fields in it .Now I want to serialize all these in to file.So I wrote the common method as shown below

```
public void SerializeToXml(Object obj){
       System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\serialize.xml", false);
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Object));
            x.Serialize(file, obj);
            file.Close();
        }
```

I will be calling that method as SerializeToXml(new Add)/SerializeToXml(new Subtract)/SerializeToXml(new Multiplication)
But I am getting exception as:

```
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o)
```

Even when Deserialize an Object

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Object));  
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("Serialize.xml", FileMode.Open);  
mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream)
```

Comment: You can't serialize "Object"; XmlSerialization serialized just public properties of public class - "Object" type doesn't have any. You need to provide your own POC class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());  
FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream("Serialize.xml", FileMode.Open);  
mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream, obj);
```

does it work for you?

Comment: tried it but XmlSerializer is not accepting obj.GetType() argument

Comment: oh sorry i did overread something..
you have two problems..

    public void SerializeToXml(Object obj){
       System.IO.StreamWriter file = new     System.IO.StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.Speci    alFolder.Desktop) + @"\serialize.xml", false);
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            x.Serialize(file, obj);
            file.Close();
        }

This should solve your issue 1.

Comment: Your second issue is, 
use e.g. `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Add));`

`var add = (Add)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);`

So your Object should get deserialized fine..

What you cannot do is deserialize to object and get Add, Subtract, e.g. automatically.

Comment: XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());  XmlSerializer is not accepting obj.GetType() as argument its throwing an error for issue1

Comment: please post the full method signature, of where your issue is. you may have used a different param name than obj of course.